# It is not allowed to use stages more than once [Jenkins_Declarative_Pipeline]

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am completely new to the jenkins pipeline. I'm trying to create a project with multiple stages but in my `Import` stage , I want to execute `parallel`. For each `stage` in `parallel` , I have again multiple `stages`. I'm trying the following way, but getting syntax error as `It is not allowed to use stages more than once`.Can someone correct me how to achieve this, I have tried some online resources but unable to get clear syntax.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'from build'
      }
    }
  }

    stage('Test_A') {
      parallel {
        stages("GUI") { stage("Tests_A") { steps {echo 'from A'}} stage("Archive") {echo 'from Publish' } }
        stages("API") { stage("Tests_B") {steps {echo 'from B'} } }
        stages("CLI") {  stage("Tests_C") {steps {echo 'from C'} }}

      }
    }

  }
```

I want to create something like this where a parallel stage will have a sequence of stages

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `parallel` block can only have `stage` children:

```
stage('Import') {
    parallel {
        stage("Import_A") { 
            stages {
                stage("Tests_A") { steps { echo 'from A' } } 
                stage("Publish") { steps { echo 'from Publish' } }
            }
        }
        stage("Import_B") {
            ...
        }

        ... and so on
    }
}
```

Also see [example of official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel).